# image doesn't resize based on the container it's in. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I'm just trying to get an image to resize to stay within it's div, but it continues to spill over onto the div below when I reshape my browser size or view in my laptop.

I haven't set any fixed dimensions. I am using bootstrap v5 and tried 2 image classes in the code.

I realise my code may contain some unrequired items and doubling of commands etc., but they are all things I tried with no avail. An example screenshot of my issue.

[image: screenshot of issue]

The only thing I've not yet done (and is my last option if I can't get the image to scale within the divs) will be to create more breakpoints and corresponding CSS for them. However the image doesn't spill out of it's divs on mobile devices and seems to in part be responsive - so I'm not sure if this is necessary. And it seems like there should be a simpler solution to what I'm trying? Perhaps not.

Many thanks.

```css
#cover2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), url("https://www.kelvindalewhisky.com/public/img/2.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper img {
  height: 80%;
  width: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="cover2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="https://www.kelvindalewhisky.com/public/img/kelvindalegold.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid" class="img-responsive">
          <br><br>
          <a href="index.php#example"><span style="font-size: 60px; color: #ec894b;"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down icn_blue wow shake"  data-wow-duration="1500ms"></i></span></a>
        </div>
        <!-- container ends-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row ends-->
  </div>
  <!-- container ends-->
</section>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. You're using responsive image classes from two different versions (and incorrectly in two separate class attributes).

Comment: Other tips: You really shouldn't be mixing Bootstrap row/column layout with your custom flex layout. That's a recipe for headaches. Use one or the other (and Bootstrap provides all the [flex options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) you likely need anyway). Also, don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not what they're for. Use Bootstrap's [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/). And don't use inline styles, especially when you're already set up with a stylesheet. That just makes a mess for all involved.

Comment: Please revise the snippet demo above so it actually shows your problem.

Comment: Thanks isherwood - I'm using bootstrap 5.1.

 I just noted when I removed the 100% from the cover height this seemed to extend the div (required to scroll) on and stop the image spilling onto the other div.  I'll play around with that and will remove some of the responsive classes and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry - wasn't really sure how to revise the snippet to show my issue without pasting all the code in there for the site? Anyway, I changed height 100% to min-height 100% in the #cover2 section ID. It sort of solves my issue in that the image isn't spilling over the cover div anymore, but the size of the image isn't actually changing, as it's container changes.

Comment: Are you talking about the background image or the logo?

Comment: Sorry - I see how that's confusing. 
I'm trying to reduce the size of The logo - in the image above you see it spilling into the next div.   However, when I changed the background image height to min-height 100% it then expanded so the Div wasn't overlapped. It was a kind of solution, but not really what I was after. I wanted the image to reduce in size. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You set 2 times the attribute class.

Try with  `<img src="public/img/kelvindalegold.png" alt="..." class="img-fluid img-responsive">`

Comment: Thanks cesare. This didn't seem to have any impact unfortunately.